# error in wp_title on year archive - undefined index 00

Tags: wp-title

In the year archive page in the title tag i get

```
Notice: Undefined index: 00 in wp-includes\locale.php on line 271
```

In the header.php i use:

```
<title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
```

I even tried to use in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```

My question: is WordPress fault or my theme fault?
I search on Google the notice and i found dozen of sites with this error on their titles.
My temporary fix is to check if is year archive page and set the title.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about letter "m".

Yoast SEO use $_GET['m'] in it's code and this creates a conflict.

Change your $_GET['m'] to e.g $_GET['mon'] and problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported on the issue tracker of Wordpress but decided as "Won't fix" since the notice triggers when the input is not correct.

It seems that you have a logic issue or something wrong with your data since it's calling the month number 0 (which doesn't exist).

Without any more precision I won't be able to help you more I'm afraid.

Comment: when i go for year archive the parameter in the link is ?m=2014